Docker compose find .env variables only if at the same diretcory and called .env
I have the following hierarchy:
docker-compose.yml

deployer/.env

My deployer service:
deployer:
    image: jenkins:docker_noroot
    build: ./common/jenkins/.docker
    user: "${ID_USER}:${ID_GROUP}"
    env_file:
      - ./deployer/.env
    container_name: central-deployer
    volumes:
      - $PWD/deployer/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - infrastructure

Now the .env works if I put .env file from deployer to base dir (the same as docker-compose.yml), otherwise I get this warn:
"WARN[0000] The "ID_USER" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "ID_GROUP" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
I would need to launch the container by calling the env file from deployer and not in the base directory. How can I solve this problem?
